# DateTime Comparison in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to compare `DateTime` in SQL Server. But I am using `Varchar` datatype in Table. So I am using `CONVERT` in SQL.
**My Query :**

```
Select io.* from tblData as io INNER JOIN tblInterest as ui 
ON ui.SubCatId=io.SubCatId 
Where ui.UserId=@UserId 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME,io.Start,103 <=CONVERT(DATETIME,@Start,103) 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,io.END,103)>=CONVERT(DATETIME,@End,103))
```

Now, Issue is that If I am firing query directly then It is showing me data but when It executes in C# then I get black `DataTable`.

Query After writing DateTime And UserId which I get from SqlCommand.

```
Select io.* from tblData as io INNER JOIN tblInterest as ui 
ON ui.SubCatId=io.SubCatId 
Where ui.UserId=1 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME,io.Start,103)<=CONVERT(DATETIME,'15-04-2014 23:13:30',103) 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,io.END,103)>=CONVERT(DATETIME,'15-04-2014 23:13:30',103))
```

What can be the issue ?

Comment: why don't you use `BETWEEN` instead

Comment: How are you sending `DateTime` from C# ? are you sending it as a string, It is probably being sent it a different format. That is the problem with storing `DateTime` as `varchar` and then sending them as string through C#.

Comment: System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")

Comment: @DateTime type is varchar(50)

Comment: @JeetenParmar, just a suggestion but consider using `DateTime` type instead of Varchar. As far as your C# code is concerned try `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. May be the `DateTime` separator is getting changed. But again do consider `DateTime` type.

Comment: you could also get what you are wanting by changing your code to the following but I think that you should truly use DateTime datatypes for dates 
`(CONVERT(DATETIME,io.Start,103) >=CONVERT(DATETIME,'15-04-2014 23:13:30',103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,io.END,103) < CONVERT(DATETIME,'15-04-2014 23:13:30',103))` I hope you are not hard coding the date ranges either should your 103 be 121 ?

Comment: Which, besides being ugly, means "table scan, never use an index".

Answer (score 5):

> I want to compare DateTime in SQL Server. But I am using Varchar datatype in Table.

Right here is the error. STOP THAT. You can not do that efficiently, it is a typical beginner mistake and you better stop that at the root cause, which is a non-standard way of handling datetime. Then suddenly everything else turns out to be super easy.